# bootstrap скрыть класс для телефона

Tags: css, bootstrap

Для одного из блоков на странице в bootstrap нужно убрать класс для мобильных телефонов (тип экрана xs), но разметку нужно оставить. Можно ли как то это сделать (желательно средствами самого bootstrap, без написания css кода)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Убрать класс средствами бутстрапа - нельзя. Можно либо обнулять стили класса при `@media` в CSS, либо убирать класс с помощью javascript.

---

Стилями - можно сделать так:

```
# your-styles.scss

.block.your-class {
  # ваши стили для блока с классом

  @media(max-width: $screen-xs-max) {
    # стили, обнуляющие стили для блока с классом
  }
}
```

Где `$screen-xs-max` - SASS-переменная бутстрапа, в ней хранится ширина xs-экранов.

Если вы пишете стили в CSS - значения переменных можно взять [здесь](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints), и построить стили так:

```
# your-styles.css

.block.your-class {
  # ваши стили для блока с классом
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {
  .block.your-class {
    # стили, обнуляющие стили для блока с классом
  }
}
```

---

С помощью javascript, так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $block = $('.your-block');
  if ($block.length) {
    $(window).resize(function() {
      if ($('.device-xs').is(':visible')) {
        $block.removeClass('your-class');
      } else {
        $block.addClass('your-class');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

При ресайзе окна - проверяем, виден ли особый блок `.device-xs`, и если виден - класс у блока убираем, иначе - добавляем.

Чтобы код работал - в верстке нужно разместить этот особый блок (можно сразу все бутстраповские):

```
<div class="device-xs visible-xs"></div>
<div class="device-sm visible-sm"></div>
<div class="device-md visible-md"></div>
<div class="device-lg visible-lg"></div>
```

> Глядя на все эти `device-xx` блоки и хитрости с `:visible` можно задаться вопросом: "Почему я не могу просто сравнить ширину экрана с 767px прямо в javascript? Ответ - потому что в таком случае будут погрешности, как правило из-за ширины скролла на странице. Если нужно точное совпадение с @media-запросами бутстрапа - лучше решить это с помощью хитрости выше.

Comment: у меня проект без scss

Comment: нет проблем, @media-запросы работают в CSS. А можете и через javascript решить.